# how can I get more than one item from the queue (ArrayBlockingQueue)?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, producer-consumer

Solves the problem of the producer and the consumer. However, it is extended to include a warehouse keeper.

*producer*- creates a product

*warehouseman*- takes the manufactured product from the first queue and re-sticks it to the second queue

*consumer* - takes the manufactured product with the second consecutive order

However, I do not know how I can do so that the warehouseman can take 2 products immediately and put them on the second queque(2 products on the second queque are treated as one product)

```
 the sequence of events should look like this:
    the producer creates the product -> 
    the warehouseman takes the product from the first queue ->
     the warehouseman places the product in a box and places it on the second queque-> 
    the consumer picks up the product from the second queue
```

code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ProducerConsumer {

        private static volatile int prodValue = 5;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(prodValue);
        final BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue2 = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(prodValue);
        final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        final Runnable producer = () -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    synchronized (blockingQueue) {
                        blockingQueue.put(prodValue);
                        System.out.println("Producer " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "produce  item number: " + prodValue);
                        prodValue++;
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        final Runnable warehouseman = () -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    int value = blockingQueue.take();
                    System.out.println("warehouseman " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " take itme number: " + value);
                    blockingQueue2.put(value);
                    System.out.println("warehouseman " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "  place item number : " + value + " in box");

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        final Runnable consumer = () -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    int value = blockingQueue2.take();
                    System.out.println("consumer " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " take box number : " + value);
                    Thread.sleep(1200);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            threadPool.execute(producer);
            threadPool.execute(consumer);
            threadPool.execute(warehouseman);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You might consider changing the the Object type that is on the 2nd queue. After all, it is no longer the product, it is the product in a box, as it were. So the "warehouseman" is transformative in nature, so let the queues reflect that. The "consumer" shouldn't need to know how many "things" to pull, it should just get the "packaged" products.

Comment: The first queue will not always contain a multiple of 2 items. prodValue is initialized to 5, which is not a multiple of 2. The warehouseman needs to take two products from the first queue and then "package" them into a single product and place that product into the second queue. The consumer will take a single product from the second queue which will contain the two products packaged by the warehouseman.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a blocking queue you are using, you can accept 2 items from producer and package them in a box easily without any effort.

- Also as pointed out, you need a different Object type to combine them.
- Even if the blocking queue has 1 object, assuming your producer will infinitely produce data, you can rely on blokingqueue.take() to wait till queue is non-empty again to fetch next data:
  Here is working copy:
- // CHANGE DATA TYPE FOR CONSUMER
  final BlockingQueue blockingQueue2 = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(prodValue);

code:

```
        // CHANGE DATA TYPE FOR CONSUMER
        final BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue2 = new ArrayBlockingQueue<> 
         (prodValue);

        final Runnable warehouseman = () -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    int value = blockingQueue.take();
                     int value2 = blockingQueue.take(); // HERE WE WAIT AND TAKE NEXT ITEM FROM CONSUMER
                    System.out.println("warehouseman " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " take item number: " + value + " with item number: " + value2);
                    blockingQueue2.put(value + " + " + value2); //combine 2 item to one product in next blocking queue
                    System.out.println("warehouseman " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "  place item number : " + value + " in box");

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, I do not know how I can do so that the warehouseman can take 2 products immediately and put them on the second queque(2 products on the second queque are treated as one product)

Do do this correctly, the *warehouseman* has to be a single thread.  Then that thread can just call `queue.take()` twice.  If you need the *warehouseman* to do work in multiple threads then there has to be a *grouper* single thread between the *producer* and the *warehouseman* who just groups 2 inputs together.

I would create an object something like the following which can put the 2 products onto a queue:

```
class TwoIntegers {
    int one;
    int two;
}
```

This wouldn't be necessary if all you needed to do was add the 2 Integers together but would be if more complex "products" are created.